# input name depend in array index - cannot get value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

input name depended in the index in array in this way:

```
<div id="editAboutSantences<%=i%>" class="edit-container">
       <div class="input-container">
          <label> content: </label>
          <input type="text" name="inputAboutSentences<%=i%>" id="inputAboutSentences<%=i%>" value="<%= digitalCard.about.sentences[i].content %>">
      </div>
<% } %>
```

in the controller I try to get access to this input like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < digitalCard.digitalCard.about.sentences.length; i++) {
    const sentence = digitalCard.digitalCard.about.sentences[i];
    sentence.content = req.body.inputAboutSentences+i;
    console.log('inputAboutSentences0 = '+req.body.inputAboutSentences+i);
}
```

the input:

> inputAboutSentences0 = undefined0

this is don't work because req.body.inputAboutSentences0 is object, I worked in this way in all the project and now i stuck.
Ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `inputAboutSentences*` property like:

```
sentence.content = req.body[`inputAboutSentences${i}`];
```

Using:

- [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) - bracket notation
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`${expression}`)